# How to delete data in Recycler view from another acivity

Tags: android

I have One activity in which I am reading JSONData and list in in recycler View.
I have implemented deleting data onLongClick Listener.
On click Listener I am going to Details Activity for  that item.
There I have a title, image view button for edit title and button for removing Item.`
The problem is that whether I try to remove or edit title, it does not working when get back to my first Activity.
I think I do not load data in adapter properly at the main activity.
But I do not how to do it better, any solution?
Here is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FloatingActionButton myFab;
ArrayList<ApiModel> mObjects = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 0;
    final String PHOTOS_URL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
    List<ApiModel> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myFab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        myFab.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);            
        initRecyclerView();
        adapter.setData(mObjects);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //TODO: CHECK WHY NOT WORK DELETE
        checkToDeleteOrRename();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        getJsonObjects();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         myFab.setOnClickListener(v -> {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendPhoto.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         });

        }

private void checkToDeleteOrRename() {

    Intent intentChange = getIntent();
    String flag = intentChange.getStringExtra(FLAG_CHANGE);
    String flagDelete = intentChange.getStringExtra(FLAG_DELETED);
    try {


        if (flag.equals(CHANGED)) {
            String oldTitle = intentChange.getStringExtra(OLD_TITLE);
            String newTitle = intentChange.getStringExtra(NEW_TITLE);
            adapter.changeUserName(oldTitle, newTitle);

        }
        if(flagDelete.equals(DELETED)) {
            String userToDelete = intentChange.getStringExtra(USER_DELETED);
            adapter.remove(userToDelete);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return;
    }

}

private void initRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView =  findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}


public void getJsonObjects() {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(PHOTOS_URL, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                objects = fromJson(response);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Немате активна Интернет Конекција", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayList<ApiModel> fromJson(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ApiModel photoData = new ApiModel();

                    photoData.mTitle = jsonObject.getString("title");

                    photoData.Url = jsonObject.getString("url");
                    photoData.thumbnailUrl = jsonObject.getString("thumbnailUrl");
                    mObjects.add(photoData);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return mObjects;
    }
}
```

Here is my delete and edit title methods in Second Activity

```
 public  void deleteThis(View view) {
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
} else {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
}
builder.setTitle("Delete entry")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                deleteIntent.putExtra(FLAG_DELETED, DELETED);
                deleteIntent.putExtra(USER_DELETED, mTextView.getText().toString());
                mSecondActivity.startActivity(deleteIntent);
                Toast.makeText(mSecondActivity, "User deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // do nothing
            }
        })
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .show();
```

}

```
 public void editTitle(View view) {
DialogFragmentClass dialogFragment = new DialogFragmentClass();
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"DIALOG");
```

}

And here are my methods to remove by title and edit title in my adapter

```
public void remove(String userName) {
    for (ApiModel model: data ) {
        if(model.getmTitle() .equals(userName)) {
            data.remove(model);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
} 
  public void changeUserName(String oldUserName, String newUsername){
    for (ApiModel model: data  ) {
        if(model.getmTitle().equals(oldUserName)){
            model.setTitle(newUsername);
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use [EventBus library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is by starting the Second Activity with `startActivityForResult` and depending upon the action taken by the user on Second Activity put the extras in the intent and call `setResult` and below that call `finish()`, then your MainActivity's `onActivityResult` will get called. Inside `onActivityResult` you can call your function `checkToDeleteOrRename(Intent intent)`, intent is basically that you receive inside `onActivityResult` as an argument. Hope this will help you!!!.

Comment: Still nothings happen...
                       Is this good call from second activity? 
 setResult(Deleted);
                    mSecondActivity.finish();
                    mSecondActivity.startActivityForResult(deleteIntent, REQUEST_CODE);


And this is call from adapter
   ((Activity)mContext).startActivityForResult(startSecondActivity, REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: in which activity you are calling setResult(Deleted);

Comment: Second Activity

Answer (score 0):

you go to another activity by clicking an item in recyclerview 
use staractivityforresult to goto another 2ndactivity 
also pass positon of item using put extra

and use onactivityforresult inthe 1stctivity that sets the adapter

from 2nd activity if edit or delete done use setresult to pass back edited , delete ,position params using putextra

you will get these value in 1st activity in onactivityresult

using the position, change value in the arraylist accordingly and call notifydatasetchanged